# How to maintain order of rows while joining/subqueries SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables

```
students:

      id   | name | age
      1      abc   20
      2      xyz   21

scores:

   id | studentid | marks
    1       1        20
    2       2        22
    3       2        20
    4       1        22
    5       1        20
```

where `studentid` is foreign key to students table

When a do

```
select studentid 
from scores 
where marks=20;
```

I get the following result
    `1, 2, 1`

But if want the name of the student name and when I do a join using

```
 select t1.name 
 from students t1 
 inner join scores t2 on t1.id = t2.studentid 
 where t2.marks=20;
```

I get `xyz,abc,abc` Though the ouput is correct is there any way I can maintain the order in which scores are listed in the scores table? I should get `abc,xyz,abc` as output. I tried using subquery as well

```
 SELECT name 
 FROM students 
 WHERE ID IN ( select studentid from scores where marks=20) ;
```

but that also did not give me correct order.

Comment: No order by will either sort ascending / descending not with the order its there in DB.

Comment: order by t1 .name

Comment: no this will order alphabetically by name. I want to maintain the order in which the records  are in DB.

Comment: order by scores.id

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: In SQL, in general, there is no user-observable order of "the records in the DB" - in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause, the server is free to return rows in whatever order is most convenient. If you want a guaranteed order, you need to find a way to phrase that as an `ORDER BY` clause. I think there are some wrinkles to this advice if you *are* using [tag:mysql] but it's unhelpful to rely on them if you ever expect to write SQL for other products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ;with cte as(
        select t2.id, t1.name 
         from students t1 
         inner join scores t2 on t1.id = t2.studentid 
         where t2.marks=20)
    select name from cte order by id

OUPUT
======
abc
xyz
abc
```

Comment: Thanks I am getting I get `relation "cte" does not exist` when I run on command prompt , any clue ?

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: Oh there was a small syntax error , my bad. This works like charm..Thank you!